# Getting props via state object

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to get props via state object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './counter';


class Counters extends Component {
    state = {
      counters: [
          {id:1, value:1},
          {id:2, value:2},
      ]
    };


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                this.state.counters.map(counter => (
                    <Counter key={counter.id} value={counter.value}/>))}
            </div>)
    }
}

export default Counters;



import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        value: this.props.value
    };

    constructor(){
     super();
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>

            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Why can't I get props within state object?  I am seeing props in render.
I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.
Can someone show me how to pass props correctly to the state object.  I have seen props passed this way by other coders.

Thanks,

Rob.

Comment: Where you receive this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `props` to `super` and define the state in the `constructor` or remove the constructor and use `state` directly.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-mendel-m33i2?file=/src/Counter.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return <div>{this.state.value}</div>;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

**or** [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-feather-e9cnu?file=/src/Counter.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.value
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return <div>{this.state.value}</div>;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```